# M2.3 : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool running on PHP 7.4

Tags: magento2.3.5-p2, php-7.4

While opening the admin page, getting below exception running on Magento 2.3.5-p2.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/mage235/vendor/magento/module-logging/Model/Processor.php on line 221

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/mage235/vendor/magento/module-logging/Model/Processor.php on line 221
<pre>#1 Magento\Logging\Model\Processor->initAction() called at [vendor/magento/module-logging/App/Action/Plugin/Log.php:66]
#2 Magento\Logging\App\Action\Plugin\Log->beforeDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:121]
```

Refereed [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/321542/notice-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-bool-php-7-4) but its custom code so it un-related.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade to PHP 7.3
Magento 2.3.5 does not support PHP 7.4